# Не работает правильно условие Си

Tags: c, условия

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой в условии.

Задача: В игре в дурака участвуют 4 человека. Используется колода 36 карт.

Первым ходит тот, у кого меньший козырь. Поэтому после раздачи карт участники одновременно говорят свой меньший козырь.

Определить минимальное  количество совравших.

Ввод: четыре цифры (6-14,0), где цифры больше 10 соответствуют картинкам.

Вывод: минимальное количество совравших.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ int a,b,c,d;
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
int z = 2;
int w = 3;
scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
if (a == b && a == c && a == d){
    if (a == 0){
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d",w);
    }
}
else if(a == b && a ==c){
    if (a == 0){
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d",z);
    }
}
else if (a == b){
    if (c == d){
        if ( a == 0){
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else{
            if (c == 0){
                printf("%d",y);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",z);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (a == 0){
            printf("%d",x);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",y);
        }
    }
}
else if(a == d){
    if (b == c){
        if (a == 0){
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else{
            if (b == 0){
                printf("%d",y);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",z);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (a == 0){
            printf("%d",x);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",y);
        }
    }
}
else if(a == c){
    if (b == d){
        if (a == 0){
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else{
            if (b == 0){
                printf("%d",y);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",z);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (a == 0){
            printf("%d",x);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",y);
        }
    }
}
else if (b == c){
    if (a == d){
        if (b == 0){
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else{
            if (a == 0){
                printf("%d",y);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",z);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (b == 0){
            printf("%d",x);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",y);
        }
    }
}
else if(b == d){
    if (a == c){
        if (b == 0){
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else{
            if (a == 0){
                printf("%d",y);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",z);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (b == 0){
            printf("%d",x);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",y);
        }
    }
}
else if(c == d){
    if (a == b){
        if (c == 0){
            printf("%d",y);
        }
        else{
            if (b == 0){
                printf("%d",y);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",z);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (c == 0){
            printf("%d",x);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",y);
        }
    }
}
else if(a == b && a == d){
    if (a == 0){
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d",z);
    }
}
else if(b == c && b == d){
    if (b == 0){
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d",z);
    }
}
else if (a!= b && a!= c && a!=d && b != c && b != d && c !=d){
   printf("%d",x);
}
    return 0;
}
```

В чем заключается проблема.

Проблема в том, что при вводе данных 7 8 8 8
Выводится 1, а должна выводиться 2.

Comment: И зачем такая длинная макаронина? просто посмотрите максимальное количество совпавших *ненулевых* ответов...

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например, так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int c[9] = {0};
    for(int i = 0, v; i<4; ++i)
    {
        if (1 !=scanf("%d",&v)) return 1;                // Error
        if (!((v >= 6 && v <= 14) || v == 0)) return 1;  // Error
        if (v) c[v-6]++;
    }
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        if (max < c[i]) max = c[i];
    if (max >= 1) printf("%d",max-1);
    else printf("0");
}
```

Comment: А если в задаче не использовать циклы?  Можно ли тогда найти повторяющиеся элементы?

Comment: Любите макароны? :) Ну, [держите](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jhme0pV4v1EnPtCr3208CgtqxVLaeFMH/view?usp=sharing)...

Comment: Смешно) Но лучше бы указали на мою ошибку)

Comment: Ну пройдите с отладчиком... Итак, для 7 8 8 8 попадаем в `if (b==c)`, оттуда в else (так как a != d), оттуда в `else` — так как и != 0. Выводим `y`. Почему вы считаете, что при этом надо выводить 1 — это уже смотрите сами. Вы ни разу не озаботились тем, чтоб для случая `b==c` посмотреть, а не равно ли оно еще и `a`. Вот и ошибка.